# Doxygen does not generate callgraphs in LaTeX

Tags: graph, latex, call, doxygen

I have the weird issue, that Doxygen creates all the callgraphs and puts them correctly in my HTML File, but there is no Graph whatsoever in my LaTeX sheet.
Attached you find the relevant Information.
Thanks for helping me out =)

Language: C;
Doxyfile:

```
# Doxyfile 1.4.5

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT_NAME           = BA16_sbrw_1
PROJECT_NUMBER         = "Version 1.0"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = C:/Users/Daan/workspace_v6_1/PM_Sensorless
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = German
USE_WINDOWS_ENCODING   = YES
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = "C:/Program Files (x86)/doxygen/bin/"
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
DETAILS_AT_TOP         = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = NO
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = C:/Users/Daan/workspace_v6_1/PM_Sensorless
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py
RECURSIVE              = NO
EXCLUDE                = C:/Users/Daan/workspace_v6_1/PM_Sensorless/PM_Sensorless-DevInit_F2803x.c
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = YES
PAPER_TYPE             = a4wide
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to external references   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
DOT_PATH               = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin"
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_WIDTH    = 1024
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_HEIGHT   = 1024
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 1000
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to the search engine   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
```

Comment: From the Doxyfile it looks like you are using 1.4.5 of doxygen is this correct? The current version of doxygen is 1.8.11. What happens when using this new version, also upgrading your Doxyfile to this version and checking the settings in the updated file?

Comment: Hi Albert, Thanks. That solved my Problem. I had both versions on my Computer but accidentally used the old one